# Separate login with credentials and login with certificate in Spring Boot Security

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security, thymeleaf, client-certificates

I want to have two logins. In my navbar I have two links:

- Login, which leads the user to a basic user/password formulary
- Cert Login, which I intend it to be a login where you can select any personal certificate from the Certificate Store and authenticate.

So far, both of them work, but I don't want the Certificate Selector popup to do so when I go to basic Login.

My SecurityFilterChain:

```
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .csrf(csrfCustomizer -> csrfCustomizer.disable())
        .cors(withDefaults())
        .headers(headersCustomizer -> headersCustomizer.frameOptions(withDefaults()).disable())
        .httpBasic(withDefaults())
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeHttpRequests -> authorizeHttpRequests
            .requestMatchers("/logincert/**").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated() )
        .formLogin(formLogin -> formLogin
          .loginPage("/login")
          .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
          .permitAll())
        .x509(x509 -> x509
          .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
          .subjectPrincipalRegex("CN=(.*?)(?:,|$)"));

    return http.build();

  }
```

/login is the default request in Spring, and /logincert (I don't know if this is necessary):

```
    @GetMapping("/logincert")
    public String securedData(@AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails userDetails) {
        if (userDetails != null) {
            return "Welcome, " + userDetails.getUsername() + "!";
        } else {
            return "Authentication failed.";
        }
    }
```

My intention is to disable the Certificate Selector popup in Login, and forcing it in Cert Login

Comment: create two different SecurityFilterChains